# Not able to stop vibration

Tags: java, android, android-vibration

I am developing an android game in which for vibration I am using this code

```
public void gameover() {
    prefs = activity.getSharedPreferences("AUTHENTICATION_FILE_NAME", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
    String vibration = prefs.getString("vibration", null);
    if(vibration != null) {
        if(vibration.equals("on")) {
            Vibrator v = (Vibrator) activity.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            v.vibrate(100);
        }
    }
}
```

but it is vibrating continuously. I want to stop this vibration after 100 miliseconds but its not stopping. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

try this.. it will help you..

```
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) activity.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
v.cancel();
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all make object of vibrator

```
Vibrator vb = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
```

then declare this code on button's onclick event.

```
long[] pattern = {0, 1000, 0};
                vb.vibrate(pattern, 0);
```

for cancelling vibration then use

```
vb.cancel();
```